# How can I print space separated tuples of cartesian product of 2 lists using list comprehension?

Tags: python-2.7

I have written the below code:

```
import itertools
for each in list(itertools.product(list1,list2)):
    print each,
```

It works fine, but I want to learn how to write to print each tuple of this cartesian product list in the same line separated by a space using list comprehension.

Ouput should be something like:

(1, 3) (1, 4) (2, 3) (2, 4)

is list1 = [1,2] & list2 = [3,4]

I tried but syntax error comes. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want (in Python3, for Python2, just remove the parentheses and put a space after print):

```
print(str([ each for each in list(itertools.product(list1,list2)) ])[1:-1].replace(", (", " ("))
```

Hope that helps! I really don't know why you would want to do that though. Also, note that with this solution you end up with a string and not a list even though the output is the one specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code(in python 3):

```
from itertools import product
a = "1 2"
b = "3 4"
A = map(int, (a.split(' ')))
B = map(int, (b.split(' ')))
print(' '.join(map(str, product(A, B))))
```